# How does Word Wrap work in SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, indentation, text-indent

When I have `Word Wrap` enabled and the document gets long and a lot of nested HTML elements are there, then down the line only one character per line is displayed at the right side (due to constant indentation of nested elements ). How do I overcome this situation? How do I deal with it?

[image: looks nice]

[image: nesting is getting content to right]

[image: 2 and later 3 characters per line]

Comment: disable word wrap?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot to help us visualize the problem you're seeing?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coding with Word Wrap enabled, the comments will be wrapped while the indentation will be kept. This results in only a few symbols for each line.

If you open Sublime Text's Command Palette and type in `Word Wrap: Toggle`, the lines will no longer be wrapped and you'll be able to see the comments normally. Using this command again will restore the wrapping to the default.

*Example code with Word Wrap disabled:*

[image: Code with Word Wrap disabled]

*Code with Word Wrap enabled:*

[image: Code with Word Wrap enabled]

Comment: Thanku You are right. One thing. What is the purpose of Word Wrap?

Comment: Well, the purpose is that you don't have to scroll left to right, which may be handy if you don't have a scrollwheel or don't want to scroll all the time. Also, you may have a better overview of your code as everything is on your screen with word wrap enabled.

Comment: Aren't the descriptions for the screenshots supposed to be the other way around?

Comment: @DetachedLaconian You're absolutely right, I've improved the answer. Thank you!